# What do Caucasians see in their peripheral vision, and how is their visual field?

Tags: physiology

I am an Asian who has no idea how much of their nose Caucasians (especially for those with extremely deep-set eyes, very prominent and low brow ridges, and high noses like Brian Shimansky or Rishi Idnani) can see. I also wonder if they are distracted by their nose.

Also, what are their visual fields (nasal, upward, and downward) in degrees?

These articles have made me think of this question: http://pizzawithrice.blogspot.com/2012/08/wondering-about-white-people-visual.html?m=1

https://www.quora.com/Not-to-be-racist-but-why-do-Asians-have-smaller-eyes-and-does-it-affect-their-vision (comment of 3rd answer by Dale Thomas: "I did always want to ask. Do Caucasian men see their eyebrows and forehead? Is there any impact on vision?")[image]

Comment: I think we only needed to see the face from the picture!

Comment: Speak for yourself @Remi.b. Haha!

Comment: There is quite a diversity of noses among caucasians too. As a caucasian with a somewhat similar nose than the guy on the picture (but not as extreme), I can say that I am able to see the "bulgy part" of my nose if I cross my eyes. If I point my eyes toward the right and close my right eye (and vice-versa on the left), I can see a fair part of my nose. If my right eye is left open, the I can barely notice the presence of my nose. I have never felt like my nose was a distraction in my visual field, no $\ddot \smile$

Comment: @Remi.b Do you see your entire nose or just most of it? If your nose is shined on, such as by sunlight or overhead halogen lights, does it become more noticeable?

Comment: No, I don't think I can see my entire nose although that depends upon when you define being the start of the nose. There is no particular lighting that makes my nose more noticeable in my field of vision. I suspect that you can also see some of your nose as you cross your eyes (at least the tip) but it does not bother you at all. It is the same, it really never bothers me in any way.

Comment: @Remi.b I define the start of nose as the bridge of nose (glabella). Do you see your nose bridge? Where it meets the eyebrows? What about your eyebrows? Also, the horizontal skin below/behind your eyebrows (top of eye socket/bottom of brow ridge)?

Comment: I can almost see my nose bridge but not quite.

Comment: If I look up my vision is just barely obscured by my brows, particularly if scrunched up